# I have a list with urls-pdfs and i want to save them locally to my pc

Tags: python, pdf, download, urllib

I am new in python so i have the specific json and i have extracted the 
documentElement value from the dictionary  and then made it a list...How to download this pdfs automatically to a directory folder?

```
import urllib.request
import requests
import json

url = 'https://diavgeia.gov.gr/luminapi/api/search/export?q=decisionType:%22%CE%93%CE%9D%CE%A9%CE%9C%CE%9F%CE%94%CE%9F%CE%A4%CE%97%CE%A3%CE%97%22&OrganizationUid:%2250024%22&status:%22%CE%91%CE%BD%CE%B1%CF%81%CF%84%CE%B7%CE%BC%CE%AD%CE%BD%CE%B7%22&page=1&size=4&wt=json'


#get urls
response = requests.get(url)
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as u:
    data = json.loads(u.read().decode())
#add links to the list
pdf_links = list()
for key in data:
    for x in data[key]:
       pdf_links.append(x['documentUrl'])
#print
print(pdf_links)
```

Comment: You would have to ask for specific programming problems. Tell us what you did and how you could not achieve your goal. Do not ask others to write your code for you. Please refer to the Help Center on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://diavgeia.gov.gr/luminapi/api/search/export?q=decisionType:%22%CE%93%CE%9D%CE%A9%CE%9C%CE%9F%CE%94%CE%9F%CE%A4%CE%97%CE%A3%CE%97%22&OrganizationUid:%2250024%22&status:%22%CE%91%CE%BD%CE%B1%CF%81%CF%84%CE%B7%CE%BC%CE%AD%CE%BD%CE%B7%22&page=1&size=4&wt=json')
for doc in response.json()['decisionResultList']:
    r = requests.get(doc['documentUrl'], stream=True)
    with open('{}.pdf'.format(doc['ada']), 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r:
            f.write(chunk)
```

Following files has been downloaded to my PC:

[image]